# Firebase Service is not working properly , I send notification but nothing happen

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've developed an application that uses the Firebase Cloud Messaging service. It was working and it stopped and i don't know why. I've tried to recreate the project either on the FCM console or on Android studio but nothing worked. Kindly I'm asking to check my code.

**manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="web.usama.fiver.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MyFirebaseMessagingService Class**

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String s) {
        super.onNewToken(s);
        Log.e("TOKEN",s);

    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        Log.e("Body",remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
        if(remoteMessage.getData().isEmpty())
            showNottification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(),remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        else
            showNottification(remoteMessage.getData());


    }

    private void showNottification(Map<String, String> data) {

        String title=data.get("title").toString();
        String body=data.get("body").toString();

        Intent intent=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent= PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);



        NotificationManager notificationManager= (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        String Notification_Channel_ID="web.usama.fiver.myapplication";

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(Notification_Channel_ID,"notification",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            notificationChannel.setDescription("Subhi Channel");
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0,1000,500,100});
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);


        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,Notification_Channel_ID);
        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true).setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setContentInfo("Information");
        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(new Random().nextInt(),  notificationBuilder.build());



    }

    private void showNottification(String title, String body) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager= (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        String Notification_Channel_ID="web.usama.fiver.myapplication";


        Intent intent=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent= PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(Notification_Channel_ID,"notification",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            notificationChannel.setDescription("Subhi Channel");
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0,1000,500,100});
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);


        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,Notification_Channel_ID);
        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true).setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setContentInfo("Information");
        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        notificationManager.notify(new Random().nextInt(),  notificationBuilder.build());


    }
}
```

The Build.gradle and the app.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Also,

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "web.usama.fiver.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not seeing instance ID service in your manifest:

```
<service android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIdService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

I see onNewToken but I have no idea what that is. onTokenRefresh is the function from the instance ID service.
Also make sure you are using the correct token, if you re-installed the app at any point, the token changed.